# How to initialize input fields without writing "if statements"?

Tags: java, design-patterns, if-statement, enumeration

I have an enum like

```
public enum Field {
     A, B, C, D, E ....;

     private Field(){
     }
}
```

I have a `class Panel` that takes `Field array` to initialize the fields:

```
public class Panel {
     TextBox A; 
     TextBox B;
     TextBox C;
     TextBox D;
     TextBox E;
     ...


     public Panel(Field[] fields){
          this.fields = fields;
          init();
     }

     public void initA(){}
     public void initB(){}
     public void initC(){}
     public void initD(){}
     public void initE(){}
}
```

My question is, how can I initialize the fields that given without writing many if statement?

I can't find any solution and I'm now initializing like this:

```
public void init(){
      for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.length; i++){
          if(fields[i] == Field.A){
              initA();
          } else if(fields[i] == Field.B){
              initB();
          } else if(fields[i] == Field.C){
              initC();
          } else if(fields[i] == Field.D){
              initD();
          } else if(fields[i] == Field.E){
              initE();
          }  ....
      }
}
```

Comment: (-1) from me, because the OPs comments to answers show, that the question is incomplete, there are a lot of unwritten additional requirements for an "acceptable answer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your design might need to be looked at.  A few suggestions:

- Add the init method to your enum.  So
  then you can iterate around the array
  of your enums and call the init
  method on it, so the enum knows how
  to do its own initialization
- create a    Command object which does
  the    initialization and create a
  Map of    your enum as the key and
  the Command    as the value.  Cycle
  round the map    running the Command
  for each enum.
- Use reflection - cost wise I wouldn't be too concerned for this, unless your system is after incredibly low latency

For the first bullet, you could change the TextBox to hold a Field type against it e.g.

```
TextBox A = new TextBox(Field.A);
TextBox B = new TextBox(Field.B);
```

So if TextBox knows it is A,B,C,D,E then you just need to loop around your Field[] and when it finds its mathing TextBox run the init code (which can be stored against the specific enum instance).  Of course you will need to register all your TextBox instances in a data structure somewhere, as you seem very set against using the very widely used reflection API.

In essence there has to be a link between the Field and the TextBox.  Java cannot read your mind and know this without you telling it.  Well, at least until Google unveil their telepathy API (and that would probably only be for Go...).  This can be done based on naming (reflection), hardcoded logic (ifs or switches) or based on state.  For the latter this means associating the Field with the TextBox, as I have demonstrated with the Constructor example above.

Comment: @planetjones again I should check if the Field.A then init TextBox A and B and E like that. it is not the solution think

Comment: @hilal - You asked for a solution *without many many if statements*. Nothing else.

Comment: @Andreas_D yes but writing reflection and/or switch is not an OO approach

Comment: @hilal - you didn't even ask for an OO approach. All those additional requirements for an "acceptable answer" should have been in the question!!

Comment: @Andreas_D ok Andreas. I think you are nervous right now but please look at the tags before any "!".

Comment: @hilal - nervous is not the correct word. Please have a look at the FAQ, it may help you to improve your relationship with people that spend their time on helping on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective I'd choose a combination of *Factory pattern*, *Singleton pattern (enum based)* and *Command pattern*. I see a set of *commands* where each command is specific for a given value. A *factory* (*Singleton*) is a common pattern to create such specialized instances. *Even though* it simply moves the if/switch chain into the factory (but factories are allowed use conditional checks in order to create the instances..).

```
// the init command
public interface PanelInitializer {
  public init(Panel p);
}
```

---

```
// the factory
public enum PanelInitializerFactory {
  INSTANCE;

  public PanelInitializer create(Field field) {
    switch (field) {
      case A: return new TypeAInitializer();
      case B: return new TypeBInitializer();
      case C: return new TypeCInitializer();
      //..
    }
  }
}
```

I don't think that we can get rid of *all* conditional checks without using naming conventions and reflection/instantiation or without introducing the constraint, that all initializers share the same code.

Answer (score 1):

You can, as @planetjones mentioned, add an `init()` method to your enum class. The init method should return a reference to the initialised `TextBox` of its (enum) type. If you need to pass data to the initialisor you can pass `this` so that it can retrieve any information it needs.

To get around the problem of finding the variable to assign to, you can either declare an array of `TextBox`es

```
public void init(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.length; i++){
      F[i] = fields[i].init(this);
  }
}
```

or assign them after you initialised a temporary array.

```
public void init(){
  TextBox F[5];
  for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.length; i++){
      F[i] = fields[i].init(this);
  }
  A = F[0];
  B = F[1];
  C = F[2];
  D = F[3];
  E = F[4];
}
```

Of course you should declare constants instead of using magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet featuring adding the init method to the enum.  In each Field's init method you can call one of your different initX() methods.  Making the init method abstract gets the compiler to remind you to define your init method for the enum value.

```
enum Field
{
  A{public void init(){initA();}},
  B{public void init(){initB();}},
  C{public void init(){initC();}},

  public abstract void init();
}
```

Comment: After posting I noticed that a few others had already suggested adding the init method to the enum.  @rsp shows how you'd call the initialization on the field array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java reflection to loop through your enum, but you really should look into some way to consolidate all your initN() methods.

Comment: thanks for your answer . I know that I can do it with reflection but it is very ineffective

Comment: You don't need reflection to loop over the enum value. `for(Field field: Field.values())` will do nicely.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd - Well the reflection part was for calling the initN() methods by constructed names.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it, for example, by moving initialization logic to the enum. Have there a method initialize that takes a TextBox as the parameter and initializes it.

BTW you would be better having the TextBox variables in an array.

**EDIT**
Another option is, what I often is I use an enum as a sort of archetype storage. There I have a method returning an object which matches a certain enum type.

If you do not want to have initialization in enum you could move it to objects you are going to return. There for each particular object you will have a separate initialization.

*I am afraid that you are trying to chase the dragon with this one.*
Look at it this way. Since the problem of yours is 'conditional', i.e. you have to do a different initialization depending on enum type of a Field, thus at some point you will have to use ifs or switch statement.

Believe there is no magic way around it, how the program should know what you want to do? Even using reflection you will use ifs, etc. to initialize it accordingly.

Comment: again I chould check with "if" that if Field.A then init Textbox A else if Field.B then init Textbox B ... same logic many "if"

Comment: @hilal - if the enum *knows* how to initialize then you don't need any conditional statements.

Comment: @hilal check the EDIT. I write there about yet another option you could take. This way you might achieve it. Have the enum return object which then knows how to initialize itself. I cannot imagine another way around it. But why do you mind ifs in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Why you current implementation is bad? Only because it looks "ugly"? You can use switch instead of bunch of if:

```
  public void init(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.length; i++){
        switch(fields(i)){
          case A:
            initA();
            break
          case B:
          ...
        }
    }
  }
```

Maybe logic in initA, initB... is very similar? If you have 20 different enums, and 20 different init to run, not much space for improvement...

Comment: +1 for providing a good answer and because all clarifications *should go to the question, not to some comments*

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not at all bad if the init methods associated with each TextBox is very different, and the list of Fields is small. Also, if you typically instantiate only one of these Panel instances, the other approaches can actually hurt more than help.

Having said that, consider using a [java.util.EnumMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). After that, you have three choices:

1. register the TextBoxes in some other array as well,
2. invoke the `initA`, ... using reflection or
3. invoke them using some functor construct.

The best choice depends on use case.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FooPanelMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FooPanel panel = new FooPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}    

class FooPanel extends JPanel {

    // fields are dynamically created, so we put them into a map
    private Map<PanelField, JLabel> fields = new HashMap<PanelField, JLabel>();

    // enum to configure the fields
    private enum PanelField {
        FIRST("first text"), 
        SECOND("second text"), 
        LAST("last text");

        private String text;

        private PanelField(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getLabelName() {
            return text;
        }

    }
        // constructor uses the enum configuration to create the fields
    public FooPanel() {
        for (PanelField fooPanelField : PanelField.values()) {
            createLabel(fooPanelField);
        }
    }

    private void createLabel(PanelField field) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel(field.getLabelName());
        this.add(label);
        fields.put(field, label);
    }
}
```

This example can be easily turned into a abstract solution by defining an interface for PanelField, that is implemented by enums. FooPanel can be used as a base class for Panels.

Answer (score -1):

best u move the init into the enum, just like:

```
public enum Example{ 
  value1(1), 
  value2(2), 
  value3(66);

  private final int internalValue;

  Example(int value){ 
       this.internalValue = value; 
  }

  public int getInternalValue(){ 
       return this.internalValue; 
  }
}
```

Although this is really simple example, you can add any code to the constructor later on and have more complex decisions based on the actual object itself.

Comment: why add value? they all have ordinal value. it just looks like a simple enum tutorial

Comment: +1 for the idea, -1 because the example does not match the problem, so a clear "0" from me ;)

Comment: @hilal: and what if i want the enum to represent a value, that does not match the ordinal value? (SEPTET(7), OCTET(8), DOUBLE_QUARTET(8)) ... that's why i usually use constructors for more complex Enums.

Comment: @Andreas_D: ^^ maybe i got the question a little wrong; just wanted to show, how to move the decision problem at construction into the enum object. Thx anyway ;)